# RSpec: POST to another controller / POST with named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

With the following route in my routes.rb:

```
post 'fadvisor', to: 'fadvisor_url_validation#validate', as: :fadvisor, default: :json
```

I want to write some tests inside the `fadvisor_url_validation_controller_spec.rb`. Like a simple test to see if I get a successful response.

```
RSpec.describe FAdvisorUrlValidationController, type: :controller do
  let (:c_partner) { create(:c_partner) }
  let (:fadvisor) { create(:fadvisor, c_partner: c_partner, url: '/testurl') }
  it 'has a valid token' do
    post :fadvisor
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

But when I do this, RSpec tells me that: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/fadvisor", :controller=>"fadvisor_url_validation"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does your describe block look like? Does it match your controller name? Also, could you show your routes?

Comment: @alf - i updated  the questions as suggested. it seems to match - what i find strange is that the action mentioned in the error message doesn't fit to the one that i defined in the route ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you route would be:

```
post '/fadvisor', to: 'fadvisor_url_validation#validate', as: :fadvisor, default: :json
```

btw your spec would be:

```
it 'has a valid token' do
   post '/fadvisor'
   expect(response).to be_success
end
```

If you want to use rails url helper, make sure to include this:

**rspec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Then your spec becomes:

```
it 'has a valid token' do
   post fadvisor_path
   expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Comment: the route is workings this way ... so i don't think that adding the slash could be the answer :/ - thanks anyways